# How can I initiate a telegram conversation in order to send a message to a telegram user from node js

Tags: javascript

I want to use telegram from a node js script in oder to send a kind of <<"transaction success confirmation">> message, but as I saw, a bot  cannot initiate a chat enventhou you have both of user ID and chat ID, so in my case I want to start a chat with a user just like a confirmation email. If you have any idea please help me guys

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found a way to do it by using [telethon](https://docs.telethon.dev) a [python](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) librairy  to write a python script which I simply call in my node 's script because the [javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegram) alternative one did not fit to my needs